# Simple TicTacToe game in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, array, console, tic-tac-toe

I just started learning C++, and this is one of my projects. It's just a simple 2-player (No AI) TicTacToe game that runs from the console. The project was to familiarize myself with arrays, so review on how I used arrays is mostly what I'm looking for, but any other advice is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

const int SIZE = 3; //rows and cols
const char PLAYER1 = 'X';
const char PLAYER2 = 'O';
const char DEFAULT = '_';

int checkIfWin(char[SIZE][SIZE]);
void drawBoard(char[SIZE][SIZE]);
int main(){

int move = 0;
int place = 1;

//Create board
char board[SIZE][SIZE];
int placeCol[(SIZE * SIZE) + 1];
int placeRow[(SIZE * SIZE) + 1];
int counter = 1;

for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
            board[col][row] = DEFAULT;
            placeCol[counter] = col;
            placeRow[counter] = row;
            counter++;
        }
    }

int i = 0;
while(i < (SIZE * SIZE)){// Loop that goes until all possible moves are done.

    int uRow = 1, uCol = 1;
    drawBoard(board);

    //Player 1
    cout << "Player 1's turn!" << endl;
    cin >> move;
    if(board[placeCol[move]][placeRow[move]] == DEFAULT)
        board[placeCol[move]][placeRow[move]] = PLAYER1;        
    i++;

    if(checkIfWin(board) == 1){
        cout << "Player 1 one!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    //Player 2
    drawBoard(board);
    cout << "Player 2's turn!" << endl;
    cin >> move;
    if(board[placeCol[move]][placeRow[move]] == DEFAULT)
        board[placeCol[move]][placeRow[move]] = PLAYER2;    
    i++;

    if(checkIfWin(board) == 2){
        cout << "Player 2 one!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;

}
int checkIfWin(char board[SIZE][SIZE]){

int player1Count = 0;//Amount of the same char in a row
int player2Count = 0;

//CHECK VERTICAL
for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
            if(board[col][row] == PLAYER1){
                player1Count++;
            }else if(board[col][row] == PLAYER2){
                player2Count++;
            }
        }
        if(player1Count >= SIZE)
            return 1;
        if(player2Count >= SIZE)
            return 2;
        player1Count = 0;
        player2Count = 0;
}

//CHECK HORIZONTAL
for(int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
            if(board[col][row] == PLAYER1){
                player1Count++;
            }else if(board[col][row] == PLAYER2){
                player2Count++;
            }
        }
        if(player1Count >= SIZE)
            return 1;
        if(player2Count >= SIZE)
            return 2;
        player1Count = 0;
        player2Count = 0;
}

//CHECK TOP-LEFT TO BOTTOM_RIGHT                     // ? _ _
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){                      // _ ? _
    if(board[i][i] == PLAYER1)                       // _ _ ?
        player1Count++;
    if(board[i][i] == PLAYER2)
        player2Count++;
}
if(player1Count >= SIZE)
    return 1;
if(player2Count >= SIZE)
    return 2;
player1Count = 0;
player2Count = 0;

//CHECK TOP-RIGHT TO BOTTOM-LEFT                     // _ _ ?
int countCol = SIZE - 1;                             // _ ? _
int countRow = 0;                                    // ? _ _
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

    if(board[countCol][countRow] == PLAYER1)
        player1Count++;
    if(board[countCol][countRow] == PLAYER2)
        player2Count++;

    countCol--; 
    countRow++;
}
if(player1Count >= SIZE)
    return 1;
if(player2Count >= SIZE)
    return 2;

return 0;
}
void drawBoard(char board[][SIZE]){
system("cls");
int counter = 1;
for(int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
        cout << board[x][y];
    cout << "     ";
    for(int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
        cout << counter << "_";
        counter++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

I am already aware that using OS specific commands like `system("cls");` is bad practice, but I figured this project was to small to make a big fuss over it- again, just to play around with arrays, I don't plan to go much further on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I would do is indent everything in block scope. It's pretty hard to read, and I didn't even know realize there was a second function at first.

I also find the C-ish approach of forward declarations then defining them after main to be annoying. It involves endless scrolling. You should try to define functions where you declare them, preferably before main. If you break everything out into functions, then main would consist of very little code, precluding the need to break the scrollbar.

Your variable names could be more descriptive as well. `SIZE` could literally mean anything and could easily be confusing in other contexts. `DEFAULT`, `move` and `place` are other examples of bad variable names.

Don't capitalize constants. This is a convention that's usually done for macros, so people will think your variables are macros.

The return values of `checkIfWin` are pretty cryptic. I can't tell what they mean just by looking at them in any given context (where you call them, and where you return them.) If I have to analyze the entire program just to figure out the return value, it's not intuitive.

Speaking of which, `checkIfWin` has a lot of duplicated functionality. It's just begging to be refactored.

All in all, I find your program to be unreadable. And while it may make sense to you now, I give it somewhere around 3 weeks before you start to struggle with reading it.

Answer (score 1):

**Break up the code**

It's never to soon to start thinking about breaking your program up into classes.  At the moment, most of your variables and processing happens in your main function.  Defining at least a `TicTacToe` class to represent the game mechanics would help you to break up your program.  Data like the `board` can then be shared amongst the methods within the class (such as `checkIfWin`), rather than having to be passed into the method.

**Move Counting**

Currently you're main game loops gets a move from player one, then a move from player two for each iteration.  This means that in the case of a draw, it still waits for player two to take a final move, even though the board is full.  It would be better to have a single move as the core of the loop, with it alternating which player is moving.

**Input Validation**

You aren't validating your input.  If the player types 'randomText', or even '10' it will result in the application blowing up.  You need to check anything you ask the user for.

**Move Validation**

Whilst you check if the board has already been played on, you don't handle it as a failed move.  So, if player 1 plays in position 1, player two can also specify it, it is ignored but then it's player 1's go again.  Play shouldn't progress to the next player until a successful move.

**Checking for Victory**

`checkIfWin` is quite naive in its approach, it checks every possible combination to see if there is a win for anybody.  You only really need to check if the current player has one.  More than that, you only *really* need to check if the current move has triggered a win.